# Existe alguma diferença na pronúncia de "para - preposição" e "para - verbo parar"?

Tags: pronúncia, diferenças-transatlânticas

Antes do AO, as duas palavras eram diferenciadas pela grafia, onde "para", verbo, recebia um acento agudo no primeiro "a".  Quanto à pronúncia, no entanto, nunca percebi qualquer diferença. Recentemente ouvi na televisão que há uma diferença de pronúncia entre as duas palavras, em pt-PT.  Caso exista, qual seria essa diferença?

Comment: +1 Também já ouvi falar disso, tomara que haja alguma resposta com links para gravações.

Comment: Nem entendo a pergunta. Uma pergunta e ele pregunta tem diferença de pronúncia? Claro que não. Que nem: Ela para o carro em cada esquina. Ele deu o presente ao seu filho para seu aniversário. Dentre milhares de otros exemplos.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Em Portugal as pronúncias são diferentes. *Para* do verbo *parar* é pronunciado *pára*, com á aberto; a preposição é *pâra*, com â fechado.
O *para* de *parar* é como no Brasil: rima com *cara* e *Sara*. A preposição podem ouvi-la [aqui no Forvo](https://forvo.com/word/para/#pt_pt) (usuário aimae); e mais três [aqui](https://forvo.com/word/parab%C3%A9ns/#pt_pt) na palavra *parabéns* (o *para* é igual nas duas palavras).

Agora, eu escutei uns tantos brasileiros no Forvo. A maioria pronúncia a preposição como *pára*, igua à forma do verbo, mas  alguns parecem-me pronunciar mais ou menos como os Portugueses. Por exemplo, aqui em [“recado para alguém”](https://forvo.com/word/deixar_um_recado_para_algu%C3%A9m/#pt), o [ricasc_88 em “para ti”](https://forvo.com/word/para_ti/#pt), ou o [alanalves96 em “parabéns”](https://forvo.com/word/parab%C3%A9ns/#pt_pt)

Em Portugal esta diferença é possivelmente parte dum padrão mais geral. A preposição *para* não tem acentuação tónica própria; ambas as sílabas são átonas. Ora os ás átonos tendem em Portugal a reduzir-se a “â” (tal como os ós átonos se tendem a reduzir a u, e os és a um som quase inaudível), o que explica o timbre fechado nos ás de *para*; já o primeiro á em *para* de *parar* é tónico, logo tem timbre aberto. Do mesmo modo o primeiro á tem timbre aberto em *Marta*, em que é tónico, mas passa a fechado em [*Martinho* (Forvo)](https://forvo.com/word/martinho_da_arcada/#pt), em que é átono. O mesmo se passa com [*casa* (Forvo)](https://forvo.com/word/casa/#pt) e *casinha* (não há no Forvo, podem ouvir na [*Minha casinha* original](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nGEEku-EwL4), segundo 15’’, ou na dos [Xutos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E5kdbIfb25I), 11’’ e 35’’).

Pela mesma razão, aquela brincadeira com o meu nome e *já sinto*, mesmo em Portugal, tem de ser dito com sotaque abrasileirado, porque no de Portugal não funciona: o *Ja*- de *Jacinto* soa diferente de *já*; nem o *Ca*- de *Capelo* soa igual a *cá*.

Comment: Muito bom! Concordo que dá para ouvir "pâra" em alguns exemplos de pt-BR, mas apostaria que esses usuários pronunciariam da mesma forma o "para" do verbo.

Comment: @stafusa, pois, mas nesse ponto eu não aposto conta ti... :)